# Trigger in MYSQL that delete

Tags: mysql

I have posted this code in another threat, but this question is slightly different. I have to make a trigger. The question sounds like this:

> "Create a trigger that removes the season if unused whenever
>   information about when and who produces a product is deleted (i.e.,
>   whenever a record is removed from the 'Produces' table, check if there
>   are other records about product being produced for the same season, if
>   not, remove also the corresponding record from the season table)"

My MYSQL code:

the MYSQL code is here:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Dvds(
Serial integer NOT NULL,
Name varchar(50),
Year integer,
Genre varchar(50),
Price integer,
PRIMARY KEY (Serial));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Shops(
Id integer NOT NULL,
Name varchar(50),
Address varchar(50),
PRIMARY KEY (Id));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Customers(
CNo integer NOT NULL,
AccNo integer,
Time varchar(50),
PRIMARY KEY (CNo));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ContactPersons(
Id integer NOT NULL,
Name varchar(50),
Phone integer,
PRIMARY KEY (Id));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Seasons(
StartDate date NOT NULL,
EndDate date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (StartDate,EndDate));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WebShops(
Id integer NOT NULL,
Url varchar(50),
FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES Shops (Id),
PRIMARY KEY (Id));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Producer(
Id integer NOT NULL,
Address varchar(50),
Name varchar(50),
PRIMARY KEY (Id));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Sold(
Id integer NOT NULL,
CNo integer NOT NULL,
Serial integer NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES Shops (Id),
FOREIGN KEY (CNo) REFERENCES Customers (CNo),
FOREIGN KEY (Serial) REFERENCES Dvds (Serial),
PRIMARY KEY (Id,CNo,Serial));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Has(
Id integer NOT NULL,
Serial integer NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES Shops (Id),
FOREIGN KEY (Serial) REFERENCES Dvds (Serial),
PRIMARY KEY (Id,Serial));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Has2(
Serial integer NOT NULL,
Producer_Id integer NOT NULL,
StartDate date NOT NULL,
EndDate date NOT NULL,
ContactPersons_Id integer NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (Serial) REFERENCES Dvds (Serial),
FOREIGN KEY ( Producer_Id) REFERENCES Producer (Id),
FOREIGN KEY (StartDate) REFERENCES Seasons (StartDate),
FOREIGN KEY (EndDate) REFERENCES Seasons (EndDate),
FOREIGN KEY (ContactPersons_Id) REFERENCES ContactPersons (Id),
PRIMARY KEY (Serial,Producer_Id,StartDate,EndDate,ContactPersons_Id));
```

The trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Seasons_before_delete` 
    AFTER DELETE ON `Seasons`
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
    DELETE FROM seasonstart
    WHERE seasonstart.???????
    DELETE FROM seasonend
    WHERE seasonend.??????
    END
```

but I really don't know. My teacher told me that I could use `IF` , `ELSEIF`, `GOTOEND`? But am i on the right track? I'm really blank right now what to do, so hope someone have a suggestion, what I could do to solve this?

Comment: to format code, highlight it, then hit ctrl-k, or click the `{}` button in the editor. for small inline code bits, use backticks (`) around the text you want "coded".

Comment: @Johan - Please don't use the homework tag. It's obsolete.

Comment: I know, but it's 100% accurate here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a trigger you have 2 virtual tables.

`NEW` and `OLD`.

Obviously in a `create` trigger there is no `old` and in a `delete` trigger there is no `new`.
So if you want to use the data of the table where the change happened (the table the trigger is attached to) you use those two tables.

Because this is a `delete` trigger you'll need to use the `old` table.

So your trigger will look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Seasons_before_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `Seasons`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM seasonstart
  WHERE seasonstart.seasonID = old.ID

  DELETE FROM seasonend
  WHERE seasonend.seasonID = old.ID
END
```

Note that it makes little sense to call a `AFTER DELETE` trigger "something_something_BEFORE" :-).

Further note that I have no idea why you need an `IF` in this trigger, the `where` in the delete statement already takes care of that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried playing around with it. I´ve typed this in:

CREATE TRIGGER `Seasons_before_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `Seasons`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
DELETE FROM seasonstart
WHERE seasonstart.seasonID = old.ID
DELETE FROM seasonend
WHERE seasonend.seasonID = old.ID
END

and i get this error:
http://postimage.org/image/5sr35zrfv/

Sorry but i am pretty new at mysql. Hm i cant find the {} button? Hope you can help me again, though the code is messed up? :-/

Comment: hm a last thing.. How do i test to see if my trigger work :-/ ?
Thank you for your help until now.

Comment: My Seasons database in myphpadmin looks like this:

http://postimage.org/image/5n4yczg57/

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER `Seasons_before_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `Seasons`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM Seasons
  WHERE seasonstart.StartDate = old.ID

  DELETE FROM Seasons
  WHERE seasonend.EndDate = old.ID
END

Comment: Or maybe something like this? :-)

CREATE TRIGGER `Seasons_before_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `Seasons`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM Seasons
  WHERE Seasons.StartDate = old.ID

  DELETE FROM Seasons
  WHERE Seasons.EndDate = old.ID
END

Comment: Hope someone still are there? :-/ What about this one:

CREATE TRIGGER `before_delete_carts`  
    BEFORE DELETE ON `Producer` 
    FOR EACH ROW  
    BEGIN  
        DELETE FROM Seasons WHERE StartDate = Producer_Id.StartDate
        DELETE FROM Seasons WHERE EndDate = Producer_Id.EndDate
    END